# How to search and replace the next value after specific text in a file - PHP

Tags: php, cakephp

I want to search and replace the string from a `PO file (its a translation file for CakePHP)` after the specific character which is `#id:`

This are the sample text inside a PO file.

```
#id: 4
msgctxt "team 1"
msgid "john"
msgstr "전세계 강사와 영어회화 레슨을 받을 수 있는 서비스입니다."

#id: 5
msgctxt "team 2"
msgid "jane"
msgstr "translation here"

#id: 6
msgctxt "team 3"
msgid "jen"
msgstr "translation here"


..
and so on..
```

Example. I want to replace the strings after `#id: 5`, which has `msgctxt, msgid, msgstr`, from my database.

```
I got this column in my database msgid, msgctxt and msgstr
```

The expected output will be like this:

```
#id: 4
msgctxt "team 1"
msgid "john"
msgstr "전세계 강사와 영어회화 레슨을 받을 수 있는 서비스입니다."

#id: 5
msgctxt "team 2"
msgid "jane"
msgstr "translation here"

#id: 6
msgctxt "team 3"
msgid "jen"
msgstr "translation here"


..
and so on..
```

I have tried this one, but I don't know how to find the strings using `str_replace` inside the PO file.

```
$newContent .= '#id: ' . $po['id'] . "\n";
$newContent .= 'msgctxt "' . trim($po['msgctxt']) . '"' . "\n";
$newContent .= 'msgid "' . trim($po['msgid']) . '"' . "\n";
$newContent .= 'msgstr "'  . trim($po['msgstr']) . '"';


$file = file_get_contents($filepath);
$data = str_replace($file, $newContent, $file); // I dont think if its correct to find the string.
file_put_contents($filepath, $data);
```

PLEASE NOTE: That, `#id:` is dynamic.

UPDATE:
Sometimes, I got this data inside the PO file.

```
#id: 4
#: https://url // sometimes don't have this
msgctxt "team 1" // sometimes don't have this
msgid "john"
msgstr "translation here"

#id: 5
msgid "jane"
msgstr "translation here"

#id: 6
msgctxt "team 3"
msgid "jen"
msgstr "translation here"
```

Comment: If its just about the newline ... tried \r\n instead of \n only?

Comment: @JimPanse, thank you for your reply, but still no, because I want to search & replace the string inside the file.

Comment: I think you should use function `preg_replace()` instead of `str_replace ()`, see [Official document here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

Comment: @Neptune Yes, that's what I am thinking about, but I don't know how to match.

Comment: Packagist.org contains a number of php packages that solve your problem. look and try: https://packagist.org/?query=po%20file for example most used https://packagist.org/packages/sepia/po-parser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I think you can try this:

```
$file = <<<str
#id: 4
msgctxt "team 1"
msgid "john"
msgstr "전세계 강사와 영어회화 레슨을 받을 수 있는 서비스입니다."

#id: 5
msgctxt "team 2"
msgid "jane"
msgstr "translation here"

#id: 6
msgctxt "team 3"
msgid "jen"
msgstr "translation here"


..
and so on..
str;

$newContent = <<<str
#id: $1
msgctxt "$2"
msgid "$3"
msgstr "$4"
str;

$data = preg_replace('/#id:\s*([0-9]+)\s*\nmsgctxt\s*"(.*?)"\s*\nmsgid\s*"(.*?)"\s*\nmsgstr\s*"(.*?)"/', $newContent, $file);
```

`$1`, `$2` and `$3` refer to the origin content behind `msgctxt`, `msgid` and `msgstr`, just change it to any information you like. Also you can change `[0-9]+` into any specific id you want.

Comment: it's close enough now, but I forgot to tell that sometimes it has extra string, I updated my question above. thank you very much

Comment: @Jin try this pattern instead:`/#id:\s*([0-9]+)\s*\n(?:#:\s*(http\S+)\s*\n)?(?:msgctxt\s*"(.*?)"\s*\n)?msgid\s*"(.*?)"\s*\nmsgstr\s*"(.*?)"/`. You can use `preg_match_all()` to find all matching parts and determine whether it has extra string or not.

Comment: wow works perfectly, you save my day. thank you very much.